# spree_active_shipping ship methods not showing up at checkout

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

Hey all i am trying to integrate the `spree_active_shipping` gem for use in my spree app

the documentation is not very clear on weather anything else needs to be done in the app in order to activate these ship methods namely fedex ground to be available at checkout.

except for these 3 lines of code which i am not sure where to put them there is really nothing else and although the ship methods were created in the admin console for the life of mine i cannot seem to be able to get them to appear at checkout.

if there is anyone with any experience with getting the gm to work in spree would be great

I am using `2-3-stable` of `spree` and `spree_active_shipping`